# How to assign a statement to a variable in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

How could this following C code be done in Delphi? I tried to translate, but it seems that Delphi does not allowed this syntax. Basically, I need to assign a function to a variable like in the C code. How could this be done on Delphi?

Here is the C code of reference:

```cpp
void EnumWindowsTopToDown(HWND owner, WNDENUMPROC proc, LPARAM param)
{
    HWND currentWindow = GetTopWindow(owner);
    if (currentWindow == NULL)
        return;
    if ((currentWindow = GetWindow(currentWindow, GW_HWNDLAST)) == NULL)
        return;
    while (proc(currentWindow, param) && (currentWindow = GetWindow(currentWindow, GW_HWNDPREV)) != NULL);
}
```

And here is my attempt:

```pascal
type
  TFNWndEnumProc = function(_hwnd: HWND; _lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;

    procedure EnumWindowsTopToDown(Owner: HWND; Proc: TFNWndEnumProc;
      _Param: LPARAM);
    var
      CurrentWindow: HWND;
    begin
      CurrentWindow := GetTopWindow(Owner);
      if CurrentWindow = 0 then
        Exit;

      CurrentWindow := GetWindow(CurrentWindow, GW_HWNDLAST);
      if CurrentWindow = 0 then
        Exit;

      while Proc(CurrentWindow, _Param) and (CurrentWindow :=  GetWindow(CurrentWindow, GW_HWNDPREV)) <> 0;
    end;
```

Comment: Btw, from the GetWindow docs: *"The EnumChildWindows function is more reliable than calling GetWindow in a loop. An application that calls GetWindow to perform this task risks being caught in an infinite loop or referencing a handle to a window that has been destroyed."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi can't assign a variable inside of a `while` or `if` statement, like C/C++ can.  You need to break up the `while` statement, just like you had to break up the `if` statement on the call to `GetWindow(GW_HWNDLAST)`, eg:

```pascal
type
  TFNWndEnumProc = function(_hwnd: HWND; _lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;

procedure EnumWindowsTopToDown(Owner: HWND; Proc: TFNWndEnumProc; Param: LPARAM);
var
  CurrentWindow: HWND;
begin
  CurrentWindow := GetTopWindow(Owner);
  if CurrentWindow = 0 then
    Exit;

  CurrentWindow := GetWindow(CurrentWindow, GW_HWNDLAST);
  if CurrentWindow = 0 then
    Exit;

  while Proc(CurrentWindow, Param) do
  begin
    CurrentWindow := GetWindow(CurrentWindow, GW_HWNDPREV);
    if CurrentWindow = 0 then Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, an assignment is an *expression*, with as result the value that is assigned. That is why you can take the value of an assignment:

```
while ((a = getNextValue()) != 13) 
{
   // code of loop
}
```

In Pascal and Delphi, an assighment is merely a *statement*, not something that returns a value. So you will first have to perform the assignment and query the variable to which the assignment was done in the next step:

```
a := getNextValue;
while (a <> 13) do
begin
  // code of loop;
  a := getNextValue;
end;
```

---

Remy's code is fine, but it can be simplified a little. I had already converted the code too, and came up with:

```
type
  WNDENUMPROC = function(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL stdcall;

procedure EnumWindowsTopToDown(owner: HWND; proc: WNDENUMPROC; param: LPARAM);
var
  currentWindow: HWND;
begin
  currentWindow := GetTopWindow(owner);
  if currentWindow = 0 then
    Exit;
  currentWindow := GetWindow(currentWindow, GW_HWNDLAST);
  while (currentWindow <> 0) and proc(currentWindow, param) do
    currentWindow := GetWindow(currentWindow, GW_HWNDPREV);
end;
```